# docker container keep increasing memory usage when writing into a file in a mounted directory

Tags: linux, docker, go, memory, containers

I'm facing an issue that memory used by a container keep increasing when an app inside the container writing log into a file in a mounted directory.

I'd expect memory usage doesn't increase by this.
Does anyone have idea why it increases ?
Thank you !!

Here is what I did:

1. Write an app which just writes "hello world" into "/home/mylog/test.txt".

   ```
   func main(){
   file, _ := os.OpenFile("/home/mylog/test.txt", os.O_WRONLY|os.O_CREATE, 0666)
   defer file.Close()
   for {
       fmt.Fprintln(file, "hello world")
       }
   }
   ```
2. Build a docker image

```
    docker build -t mylog .
```

Dockerfile

```
    FROM golang
    RUN mkdir -p /home/mylog
    COPY main.go /go
    WORKDIR /go
    CMD ["go","run","main.go"]
```

3. Run a container with -v option mouting the current dir.

```
    docker run -d -v $PWD:/home/mylog mylog
```

4. Check memory usage

```
    docker stats
```

5. It's using 527MiB.

```
    CONTAINER CPU% MEMUSAGE / LIMIT MEM% NET I/O BLOCK I/O PIDS 
     100.41% 527MiB / 15.5GiB 3.32% 648B /0B 72.3MB / 0B 15
```

6. After a few seconds, it is 844.8 MiB

```
    CONTAINER CPU% MEMUSAGE / LIMIT MEM% NET I/O BLOCK I/O PIDS
     100.15% 844.8MiB / 15.5GiB 5.32% 648B /0B 72.3MB / 0B 15
```

7. It keeps increasing and the host downs in the end.

Comment: Isn't that caused by the forever loop that you made?

Comment: @DharmaSaputra: The forever loop just prints data to a file. It doesn't continually use memory.

Comment: I tried the code on my machine. Actually `defer file.Close()` never executed, and the file `test.txt` is getting bigger and bigger. Because it keeps append.

Comment: Thank you guys. The answer from Alex solved my problem. Will use file.Sync() but not everytime for performance reason.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Call this from time to time.

```
file.Sync()
```

https://golang.org/pkg/os/#File.Sync

If you do not call this it writes to memory and waits for `file.Close()` in order to commit the changes to the file.
And in this case `Close in not called` because it is in a `defer` (this means it is called when the function returns, and here it will never return since it is a never-ending for).

LE: 
Also try using:

```
file.WriteString("hello world")
```

instead of

```
fmt.Fprintln(file, "hello world")
```

Comment: Thanks! file.Sync() works. I'd like to know if you recommend to use file.Sync()  or to call file.Close() in terms of application performance.

Comment: I would call File.Sync if you are planning to continuously write to a file. Because closing the file and opening it again when I need to write, would be more labour intensive.

Comment: @AlexEfimov I am facing the same issue but there is no for loop. I have createwritestream and i am not closing it. As a best practice, I will close it but this method gets executed only at specific conditions. So basically my program is sitting idle and still, the memory is going high. Can you please tell why?

Comment: I am guessing that the stream you create is writing to memory, without writing it to disk. What is the exact code you are using?